# Keep entire word on specific column width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried some differents approaches for it, but I always came with the same results:

[image: CSS approache]
Using `word-wrap:break-word;`

[image: Using word-wrap:break-word]

How can I insert dynamically the tag and adjust it to the column width, without "breaking" the word?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Emq9/1/)

Comment: I want to display the words inserted by the user, on a column with a specific max-width, without "breaking" the words. In this case, maintaining all "tag1" as an entire word...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#game_tag_cloud span {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: What a dumbass! I have tested it, but I have associated wrongly to the `#game_tag_cloud`, and not to the `span`! Thank you :)